# Dynamic parent activity for Android up \ back navigation in Preferences menu

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, preferences

I've a **Preference activity** for a options menu in my Android app.
I've enabled the Up \ Back navigation on the **ActionBar** and I need to come back to the previous activity that called the Options menu.
For the Preference activity, I could use in the manifest:

android:parentActivityName="mypackage.com.MainActivity"

but how come back to other activies ? The Options menu is called from 4 different activities.

```
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // Enabling Up / Back navigation
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
              finish();

        }
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: this will not navigate up from the current task. this simply closes the current activity

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have declared the parent activity in the manifest like this...

```
<activity
            android:name="com.myapp.SetPreferenceActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.myapp.MainActivity"
            >
```

and then make sure to add the case into your onOptionsItemSelected method...

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Take me back to the main activity
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

if you prefer to have the up button point to a custom activity, you can just use an intent.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent changeActivity = new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class);
      startActivity(changeActivity);

                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to return always to the MainActivity. If I'm calling Menu from SomeActivity.class, I want to come back to SomeActivity.class... If I'm calling menu from OtherActivity.class, I want to come back to OtherActivity.class

Comment: I edited my answer to include the option to use an intent to go to a custom activity

Comment: I need to know in run time the Activity I'm coming from in way to return to that activity that called Menu

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the Back button is that it will get you back to the calling activity. The system maintains a back stack of activities while the user navigates the application. Do you need to override this functionality? Please be more specific.

Comment: yes, but I need to tell the back button of the ActionBar to return to the calling activity (like the physic back button of the device)